# CakePHP does not validate fields

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

So i use CakePHP 2.0.5 .

My model:

```
class User extends AppModel {
public $name = 'User';
public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'A username is required'
        )
    ));}
```

Then i at controller perform this action it works fine and gives me error because the field username is empty:

```
$this->User->create();
$this->User->save(array("User"=>array("username"=>"")))
```

But if i pass the other named field like:

```
$this->User->create();
$this->User->save(array("User"=>array("something"=>"")))
```

it does not perform validation on username field and saves empty on database even if i made rule in my model that username value cannot be empty. So where i am wrong?

Comment: Does your username field in your database have a default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html?highlight=validation#Validation%3a%3anotEmpty), it should be:

```
'rule' => 'notEmpty'
```

(notice the lack of an array surrounding the 'notEmpty')

Although it is shown that way (above) in the CakePHP book in a few places, I personally like doing it like this, as it seems to follow the rest of the validation conventions (and is shown in many places throughout the book as well):

```
'allowEmpty' => false,
```

Secondly, you need to understand the difference between "allowEmpty/notEmpty" and "required".  According to [this page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html?highlight=allowempty#allowempty):

> The difference between required and allowEmpty can be confusing.
>   'required' => true means that you cannot save the model without the
>   key for this field being present in $this->data (the check is
>   performed with isset); whereas, 'allowEmpty' => false makes sure that
>   the current field value is nonempty, as described above.

Basic translation: 'required' means any time you save that item, you MUST include that field.  While 'allowEmpty'..etc means IF you pass that field, it can't be empty.

Comment: Yes it is little confusing. But thanks for reply it was helpful.

Comment: @Ed - Glad to help! (I agree - I was quite confused the first few times working with this)  Reminder - if either of the answers helped solve your problem, it's good practice to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need `required => true` in your validation rules, this will make validation fail if the username key is not supplied. I recommend pairing it with `on => create` so it wonly happens when the row is created.

```
$validate = array(
'username' => array(
    'not-empty' => array(
        'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        'message' => 'A username is required',
        'required' => true,
        'on' => 'create'
    ),

));
```